# Django - Filter by related name twice causes duplication of objects in queryset

Tags: python, django

I am facing issues with filtering using related_name.

Here is my code: 
Basically I am first getting the department and using that to filter the LeadSources that have a One To Many relations to the Customer Information model. However, when I run the second filter, the number of Lead Sources would suddenly turn from 2 to 4, or 3 to 9 (essentially i think it squares itself im not sure why though)

```
department = UserProfile.objects.get(user=self.request.user).department
d = department.all()[0]
qs = LeadSource.objects.filter(customers__salesDepartment = d)
print(qs)
qs = qs.filter(customers__created_date__range=(start, end)) # filtering error is from here
print(qs)
qs = qs.annotate(date=TruncMonth('customers__created_date')).values('date', 'source').annotate(count=Count('source')).order_by('date')
```

Here is my models.py

```
class CustomerInformation(models.Model):
    customer_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    salesDepartment = models.ForeignKey(SalesDepartment, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    source = models.ForeignKey('LeadSource', related_name='customers', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    created_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.localdate)

class LeadSource(models.Model):
    source_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    source = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.source
```

Here is the output from the two prints above

First print:

```
<QuerySet [<LeadSource: Facebook>, <LeadSource: Twitter>, <LeadSource: Facebook>, <LeadSource: Instagram>, <LeadSource: Twitter>]>
```

Second print:

```
<QuerySet [<LeadSource: Facebook>, <LeadSource: Facebook>, <LeadSource: Twitter>, <LeadSource: Twitter>, <LeadSource: Facebook>, <LeadSource: Facebook>, <LeadSource: Twitter>, <LeadSource: Twitter>]>
```

Here is my final output (when only filtering for June 2020):

```
<QuerySet [{'source': 'Facebook', 'date': datetime.date(2020, 6, 1), 'count': 4}, {'source': 'Twitter', 'date': datetime.date(2020, 6, 1), 'count': 4}]>
```

Expected output (when only filtering for June 2020):

```
<QuerySet [{'source': 'Facebook', 'date': datetime.date(2020, 6, 1), 'count': 2}, {'source': 'Twitter', 'date': datetime.date(2020, 6, 1), 'count': 2}]>
```

Here is my CustomerInformation instances and their needed details:

```
ID: 1
Source: Facebook
Date: 2020-06-11

ID: 2
Source: Twitter
Date: 2020-06-12

ID: 3
Source: Facebook
Date: 2020-06-11

ID: 4
Source: Instagram
Date: 2020-01-01

ID: 5
Source: Twitter
Date: 2020-06-13
```

All help is appreciated, thanks all! I really do not know what is causing this error, but could it be due to me using related_name to filter twice?

Comment: Have you checked for any data duplication in your database?

Comment: The problem is that you make two JOINs on the `customer` table, one for each filter. Likely you want to filter in the *same* JOIN?

Comment: im sorry im new to django, but what do you mean by JOIN?

Comment: @jason: if you filter on a related model, it will make a JOIN in the database: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)

Comment: is there a way for me to do it using two filters? the reason why i split it up is because there was an if statement to either filter the first query by the salesDepartment or another field. Hence it was separated from the second JOIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make here *two* JOINs, since you use two separate `.filter()`s. But even with a single `JOIN`, this can result to duplicate records, since for each `customer` with `salesDepartment=d`, it will yield a result, that means that a `LeadSource` can be returned multiple time (not per se twice, if for example there are five customers with `salesDepartment=d`), it will be returned five times.

You can use [**`.distinct()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) to retrieve only unique records:

```
d = UserProfile.objects.get(user=self.request.user).department.first()
qs = LeadSource.objects.filter(
    customers__salesDepartment=d, customers__created_date__range=(start, end)
).distinct()
```

If the filtering is conditional, you can use `Q` objects:

```
from django.db.models import Q

d = UserProfile.objects.get(user=self.request.user).department.first()

my_filter = Q(customers_salesDepartment=d)
if some_condition:
    myfilter &= Q(customers__created_date__range=(start, end))

qs = LeadSource.objects.filter(
    my_filter
).distinct()
```

Comment: I tried using distinct, but it did not work as I had more annotations after that which led back to the same result, I will edit the question now to include the annotations after the filtering.

Comment: @jason: well then these are not duplicated records, since the `TruncMonth` is different, so then it is perfectly logical that it returns multiple records, since that is basically what you ask...

Comment: @jason: well if you need it per month, then of course it will return the same record for each month.

Comment: im not quite following you, sorry im new to django, but I am have 5 CustomerInformation instances in total (1 in January 2020, 4 in June 2020). Out of the 4 in June 2020, there are 2 with source 'Twitter', 2 with source 'Facebook'. Hence, I thought my output even after truncating would be count: 2 for each of the sources (Twitter and Facebook) in June 2020. However, what i received was 4 each, which really puzzled me.

Comment: @Jason: it will return records for `(Twitter, January)`, `(Twitter, June)`, `(Facebook, January)`, `(Facebook, June)`, etc.

Comment: yes, but it seems like the output does not match my database and I have no idea why, I have edited the post to include the final output and the details of my CustomerInformation instances

Comment: @jason: because the filter is first applied on the records, so if you "filter out customers", then this will not appear in the count (and if there are no records at all, it will not appear in the results).

Comment: @jason: exactly what did you expect to be the output? Can you edit the question?

Comment: I edited the question to include the expected output already, and at the same time I used your answer above (the filtering using Q) and it works! Is it due to the reason you mentioned above about two JOINS if i filter using the related_name twice? Since using your method I am combining the Q and only filtering it once. Thanks for your help! really appreciate it